# Best way to style React components for small css size for the build

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, styled-components, css-modules

I am looking into the best way to style react components, so far I have looked into:

- Styled components
- CSS modules
- SASS
- Inline styling

Does anyone have any experience of which way is best for:

- A - Using reusable variables (I know sass does)
- B - Lightweight for    build size of app

I have implemented Bootstrap/SASS so far by adding only the bootstrap sass modules needed.

Any other idea's?